# Communication problem between Keycloak 16.1.1 in https and Spring Boot - hosted using Docker Compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, https, ssl-certificate, keycloak

I have a project with Spring Boot on the backend, Angular on the frontend and using Keycloak for authentication and security. I'm currently on the production phase of the project. We've purchased an SSL Certificate and are trying to insert it in our projects.

I'm using Docker Compose for the deployment in a azure Virtual Machine. All my containers (frontend, backend, keycloack, database) are up and running and have the lock icon on the navigators (meaning the SSL certificate is inserted correctly on all of these elements of the project, I've also checked it seems to be the same certificate on all of these elements)

However the frontend can't call the backend api and when I looked closely to the backend logs I've found :

`2023-03-21 12:32:21 WARN  KeycloakDeployment:201 - Failed to load URLs from https://mydomain:8443/auth/realms/my-realm/.well-known/openid-configuration java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)`

So I assumed the problem is in the communication between the backend and keycloak. I still can't figure out where the problem is since everything is configured correctly and it used to work perfectly fine before the whole SSL certificate thing.

This is part of the Docker Compose file used:

```
.
.
.
  backend:
    image: "backend:v0"
    container_name: "backend"
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8180:443"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:mysql://projectmysqldb:3306/project_db?serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    depends_on:
       - bd
    networks:
       - mysql_backend_net
    restart: always


  frontend:
    image: "frontend:v0"
    container_name: "frontend"
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always

        
  keycloak:
    image: "jboss/keycloak:16.1.1"
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: H2
      DB_DATABASE: App
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ********
      KEYCLOAK_TLS_TRUSTSTORE_FILE: /etc/x509/https/mydomain.jks
      KEYCLOAK_TLS_KEYSTORE_FILE: /etc/x509/https/mydomain.jks
      KEYCLOAK_TLS_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: *****
      KEYCLOAK_TLS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: *****
    volumes:
      - ./certs/crt.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - ./certs/key.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
      - ./certs/mydomain.jks:/etc/x509/https/mydomain.jks
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    networks:
      - mysql_backend_net
    depends_on:
      - bdd
    restart: always
```

This is part of the .properties file on the backend:

```
####### general config
server.port=443
server.servlet.context-path=/api

####### keycloak server config -- ok
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://mydomain:8443/auth/
keycloak.realm=my-realm
keycloak.resource=my-app
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.cors=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
frontClientSecret=*********
## admin we'll be creating for config (on Keycloak) -- not the super admin of kc
adminUsername=admin
adminSecret=*****

######## SSL config
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
server.ssl.key-store=/app/mydomain.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.enabled=true

keycloak.client-keystore=/app/mydomain.jks
keycloak.client-keystore-password=*****
keycloak.truststore=/app/mydomain.p12
keycloak.truststore-password=******
keycloak.ssl-required=external
```

And finally this is the backend ./Dockerfile :

```
# Use an OpenJDK Runtime as a parent image
FROM openjdk:11

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the executable into the container at /app
ADD *.jar app.jar
COPY application.properties /app/

COPY mydomain.p12 /app/mydomain.p12
COPY mydomain.jks /app/mydomain.jks
COPY mydomain.crt /app/mydomain.crt
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

# Run app.jar when the container launches
RUN keytool -importcert -file /app/mydomain.crt -noprompt -alias mydomain -storepass changeit -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar", "--spring.config.location=/app/application.properties"]
```

I've tried adding adding the same .jks keystore on backend docker file:

`RUN keytool -importcert -file /app/mydomain.crt -noprompt -alias mydomain -storepass changeit -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`

and in docker-compose / keycloak:

```
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: H2
      DB_DATABASE: App
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ********
      KEYCLOAK_TLS_TRUSTSTORE_FILE: /etc/x509/https/mydomain.jks
      KEYCLOAK_TLS_KEYSTORE_FILE: /etc/x509/https/mydomain.jks
      KEYCLOAK_TLS_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: *****
      KEYCLOAK_TLS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: ******
    volumes:
      - ./certs/crt.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - ./certs/key.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
      - ./certs/mydomain.jks:/etc/x509/https/mydomain.jks
```

but it lead me nowhere. Also I've tried adding these properties on the backend properties file with no result:

```
keycloak.client-keystore=/app/mydomain.jks
keycloak.client-keystore-password=*****
keycloak.truststore=/app/mydomain.p12
keycloak.truststore-password=******
keycloak.ssl-required=external
```

Comment: Refer to Keycloak, from backend, not using `https://mydomain:8443/auth/` but using `http://keycloak/auth`. Backend and Keycloak lie on the same network, so you can refer to each other using their service name. In this way your http call became an "internal" http call and dosn't go through a router.

Comment: @Benny thank you for your response.. I've tried that and now the urls are successfully loaded from keycloak (working with `http://keycloak:8080/auth`) so it seemed that the connection btw kc and backend is good. But unfortunately the frontend is always unable to access the backend api, this time it gives 401 unauthorized error. I thought maybe because we're not using the same url (using `https://mydomain:8443/auth` as kc url in frontend) but we must use https on frontend therefore I can't apply same solution here.

Comment: You should set up a Keycloak env variaible: `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://mydomain:8443/auth/`

Comment: OMG !! @Benny I can't thank you enough that was it ! That was the missing piece XD 
You have just made my day ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I'm posting this answer for anyone facing the same issue. The solution was referring to Keycloak, from backend, not using `https://mydomain:8443/auth/` but using `http://keycloak:8080/auth` in the .properties file as both are on the same network so no need to go through https. And on the other hand adding the environment variable `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://mydomain:8443/auth/` on the docker-compose.yml / keycloak. And that was it ! After these modifications everything worked like a charm !